# Two papers on surface diffeomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

The following two papers appeared in the reference of a paper i was reading.It seems that neither is published formally.Is there a website where i could find them?

**A. Casson**, *Cobordism Invariants of Automorphisms of Surface*s

**J. Johannson and D.Johnson**, *Non-Bounding Surface Diffeomorphisms which Act Trivially on the Homology*

Comment: Do you see year it published?? Titles may change slightly... Have you seen in authors webpages?

Comment: They are both cited as resp. handwritten notes from 1979 and a preprint from 1980 in the paper by Bonahon here http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1983_4_16_2_237_0/

Comment: By the way, it is K(laus) Johansson. And they are again cited by Bonahon in https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100061089 .